# Find the probability that at least 2 of n balls drawn are red, given that at least 1 is red.

Tags: probability

Hello I'm new to probability. I'm learning it by myself, following the Introduction to Probability book by Joe Blitzstein. Although, by this point I have figured that I'm repeteadly commiting the same mistake. Although I cannot figure an intuitive reason of why I commit this mistake and fully understand what I'm missing.

Below I attach two short exercices which I cannot fully understand, pointing what concrete point of the exercises I do not understand. Hoping that someone can help me to understand it.

> An urn contains red, green, and blue balls. Balls are chosen randomly
>   with replacement  (each  time,  the  color  is  noted  and  then  the 
>   ball  is  put  back).  Let r,g,b be  the probabilities of drawing a
>   red, green, blue ball, respectively (r + g + b = 1).
>
> Find the probability that at least 2 of n balls drawn are red, given
>   that at least 1 is red.

The solution to this problem is the following

$\frac{P(X \geq  2)}{P(X \geq 1)}=\frac{1-P(X = 1) - P(X = 0)}{1 - P(X = 0)}$

$P(X = 0) = (1-r)^n$

$P(X = 1) = nr(1-r)^{n-1}$

But I'm not able to figure why $P(X = 1)$ equals to $nr(1-r)^{n-1}$ and not $r(1-r)^{n-1}$.

The same happens to me to other problems like:

> A hash  table  is  being  used  to  store  the  phone  numbers  of k
>   people,  storing  each person’s phone number in a uniformly random
>   location, represented by an integer between 1 and n. Find the expected
>   number of locations with no phone numbers stored, the expected number
>   with exactly one phone number, and the expected number with more than
>   one phone number (should these quantities add up to n ?).

The solution to this problem is the following:

Let $I_j$ indicate wether position j is empty or not (1 if empty, 0 otherwise).

Then $P(I_j = 1) = (\frac{n-1}{n})^k = (1 - \frac{1}{n})^k$

$\sum_{j=1}^{n}E(I_j = 1) = n(1 - \frac{1}{n})^k$

P(specific location having exactly 1 phone number stored) $ = \frac{k}{n}(1 - \frac{1}{n})^k$
Hence its expected value is $ k(1 - \frac{1}{n})^k$

So the expected number of locations with more than one phone number is $n - n(1 - \frac{1}{n})^k - k(1 - \frac{1}{n})^k$

But in this problem I'm not able to figure why P(specific location having exactly 1 phone number stored) $ = \frac{k}{n}(1 - \frac{1}{n})^k$ and not  $\frac{1}{n}(1 - \frac{1}{n})^k$.

Seems that my mistake in both exercises is of the same nature, so there is some silly concept about probability that I'm missing/not understanding well. Could someone point me what I am missing?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I think the concept or idea you are missing is arrangements. Even though the probability of exactly $1$ ball is $r(1-r)^{n-1}$, there are $n$ ways we can pick the balls. Likewise even though the probability of having exactly $1$ phone number in a specific location is $\frac{1}{n}(1 - \frac{1}{n})^k$, there are again $k$ ways of choosing the location.

Comment: Given that you are choosing with replacement, the $n$ specifies the choices regarding the location of the unique red draw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an answer to the understanding problem, not to the two specific situations. Let us consider the following **tree** modelling (for the first case) a three times repeated experiment of extracting a red, respectively non-red ball. We record only red as `1` and not red as `0`. After all, we have the following possible eight $=2^3$ outcomes:

```
                      --- 111
                     /
             ---11---
            /        \
           /          --- 110
    ---1---
   /       \          --- 101
  /         \        /
 /           ---10------- 100
*
 \           ---01------- 011
  \         /        \
   \       /          --- 010
    ---0---
           \          --- 001
            \        /
             ---00---
                     \
                      --- 000
```

It is relatively easy to extrapolate now and imagine what happens for some other values of $n$, the one ball extract experiment being repeated $n$ times. Note the "one red ball" occurs in three situations, `100`, `010`, `001`, each having the same probability $r(1-r)^2$.

This asks - i hope - the "combinatorial problem".

Note that usually people prefer to "identify" outcomes, if only the number of extracted balls are considered, above, `10` and `01` can be "unified" to one state named "one red ball", its probability is $2r(1-r)$. Doing this at the next step, we get the following "recombination tree":

```
      111
     /
    11
   / \
  1   110=101=011
 / \ /
*  10=01
 \ / \
  0   001=010=100
   \ /
    00
     \ 
      000
```

and the labels are now considered **without ordering**.
The corresponding probabilities respect the binomial law
$$
\binom nkr^k(1-r)^{n-k}\ .
$$
(The above is the probability to get $k$ red balls from $n$ ball extraction, if each extraction comes with the same probability, $r$, to extract a red ball. The binomial coefficient shows how many possibilities there are to build a "zero-one-string" of length $n$ with exactly $k$ occurrences of the one. In our case, $\binom 31=3$, there are indeed three possibilities 001, 010, 100, for such a string with one occurrence of the 1, having length three.

So far, only the red ball problem was addressed. The phone number problem is similar, more general, and they have stolen the $k$ notation, using it for the "number of steps". Please ask pointed questions to the above, if something is not clear.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer was really helpful, now I can understand everything that I missed in the previous problems. I really appreciate your help